# Calling a service from a custom button in homeassistant

Tags: home-assistant

I'm looking for help with calling a service from a custom button.
I have the following service in developer tools, and calling it works just fine.

```
service: remote.send_command
data:
  device: Livingroom-aircon
  command: "On"
target:
  entity_id: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
```

Hitting the call service button results in my aircon turning on.

In trying to add this function to a dashboard button I have the following

```
name: Livingroom Aircon
icon: mdi:fan
show_icon: true
type: custom:button-card
tap_action:
  action: call-service
  service: remote.send_command
  data:
    device: Livingroom-aircon
    command: 'On'
  target:
    entity_id: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
entity: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
```

Now, when pressing the button I get an error saying

> Failed to call service remote/send_command. required key not provided @data['command']

I've done the same thing with a normal button, and the following works...

```
show_name: true
show_icon: true
type: button
tap_action:
  action: call-service
  service: remote.send_command
  data:
    device: Livingroom-aircon
    command: 'On'
  target:
    entity_id: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
entity: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
```

So, how do I do it from the custom button (later I want to add custom graphics/info/animation)

Comment: about the difference in quotes between my developer tools command and the data in the button - if I replace the 'On' with "On", it changes back to 'On' when I save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `custom:button-card` to work you need to adjust more than just the type of the card. Have a look at the [Github](https://github.com/custom-cards/button-card) page of the project.

You need to replace `data` with `service_data` and `device` with `entity_id`:

```yaml
name: Livingroom Aircon
icon: mdi:fan
show_icon: true
type: custom:button-card
tap_action:
  action: call-service
  service: remote.send_command
  service_data: # changed
    entity_id: Livingroom-aircon # changed
    command: 'On'
  target:
    entity_id: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
entity: remote.broadlink_rm4_pro
```